# I am looking for a way to call multiple shell scripts in a serialized manner from a base shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am looking for a way to call multiple shell scripts in a serialized manner from a base shell script. Scenario:

A shell script- Base_script.sh , which will internally call:

script_1.sh ,
script_2.sh , 
script_3.sh ,

Once "script_1.sh" will finish, THEN ONLY it should call "script_2.sh" and so on.

What all methods i have tried, are somehow executing all the scripts at once.
OS: RHEL using Shell/Bash

Edit: In response to some comments, I agree, i can use (which i already did):

- script1.sh && script2.sh
- calling each script one by one (sh script1.sh; sh script2.sh ..so on)
- even tried using an array to declare the scripts and then execute each in a loop

Problem & the Solution i got:

Each script eg-"script_1.sh" was a complex one. Its all doing some kind of database benchmarking. 
The scripts were having **some function that was going in background (someFunction &)** while execution. So even though the scripts were actually getting called one by one, yet the processing of the previous scripts kept on going in the background.

Had to redesign the entire thing to get every module & functions in the "Base_script.sh" itself.

Thanks everyone for the answers though. Appreciate it !!

Comment: Do the script_1.sh, script2.sh, etc. run in the background? How do you know that the three scripts are executing at the same time? Do you mean, for example, that script2 finishes before script1 even though 1 is called first?

Comment: You can use `script1.sh && script2.sh`, this way the second script will be executed after and ONLY if the previous script was succesful (exit status 0)

Comment: Instead of just saying "all methods I have tried" -- show some of those methods, **explicitly**, and show your test procedure (and its results). Running commands one after another in shell, without a `&` to explicitly background, **automatically** waits for each to exit before starting the next -- so what we probably have here is a case where the scripts you're running are intentionally built to background themselves.

Comment: BTW, one thing I've seen folks do by mistake is try to pass arguments containing `&` symbols without adequate quoting. If you're actually running `./script1.sh http://example.com/foo?bar&baz`, then that's running `./script1.sh http://example.com/foo?bar` in the background, trying to run a command named `baz` in the foreground, and then going on to the next line in your script.

Comment: However, to allow an **exact** diagnosis, you'd need to provide a reproducer letting other folks see the problem you're reporting for ourselves.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, there's nothing needed here at all.

```
./script1
./script2
./script3
```

...will *automatically* wait for `script1` to exit before running `script2`.

---

On the other hand, what you may have here is a case where your `script1` intentionally backgrounds itself (an action also known as "self-daemonization"). One way to wait for a daemonized process to exit is to use filesystem-level advisory locking; the below uses the `flock` command for that purpose:

```
flock -x my.lck ./script1
flock -x my.lck ./script2
flock -x my.lck ./script3
flock -x my.lck true
```

Even if `script1` itself exits, if it has child processes still running that hold the file descriptor on `my.lck`, then `script2` will be blocked from starting.

Answer (score 0):

As stated you can use `&&` or if you wanted to make it more complete you can use

```
wait $!
```

which will wait for the pid of the last run command to exit. This way you can add some if statements in for validity.

Comment: If the OP was first trying `./script_1.sh` on one line, then `./script_2.sh` on a second line, etc. and still seeing the behavior they describe, then these scripts were clearly self-daemonizing rather than being explicitly started in the background. `wait` won't help in that case, since it only works with entries that exist in the shell's job control table.